# How to read encrypted data from notepad and decrypt

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm attempting to read text from a file and decrypt it using the Fernet cryptography library in Python. So i'm running a For loop which prints all of the text, while it does that I attempt to make the loop decrypt.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from inspect import currentframe

key = "kdQGjocgILOLXj6k_mkkOJOxHxXJji7kdRUTtrGZBTo="
f = Fernet(key)


def get_linenumber():
    cf = currentframe()
    return cf.f_back.f_lineno


def Main():

    choice = input("1. Write Raw Data To File For Encryption\n2. Read Data From File For Decryption\n\nEnter Option Here: ")
    if choice == "1":
        print("Init Main Successfull On Line ", get_linenumber())
        File = open(r"D:\Visual Studio Projects\Python Proj\Secure Note Storage Project\File.txt",mode="a")


        FileToEncrypt = bytes(input("Input data to encrypt, Note it will be stored as a string, then heavily encrypted with SHA-256.\n"),'utf-8')
        print("\nSuccesfully printed File To Encrypt data on line ",get_linenumber,"\nData From FileToEncrypt Var: ",FileToEncrypt)
    
        FileEncrypted = f.encrypt(FileToEncrypt)
        print("\n\n\Here is the final product: ",FileEncrypted)
        EncryptionDescription = input("What Is The Data Entered. (Explain For Future Reference!!!)\n\nEnter Here: ")
        File.write(f"{EncryptionDescription}\n" + str(FileEncrypted))
    
        File.close()


    elif choice == "2":
        print("\n\nYou Have Chosen Decryption Method!\n")
        File = open(r"D:\Visual Studio Projects\Python Proj\Secure Note Storage Project\File.txt",mode="r")
        
        for line in File:
            name = line.strip()
            num = File.readline()

            num = Fernet.decrypt(f,num)
            print (num)
           
            
            

        
          
        

    else:
        print("Sorry, We Do Not Recognise What You Have Entered. Please look at the options and think...")
        exit(0)
        
###Debug Shit
    #print(Fernet.generate_key()) # so i can find one key and keep it static:) 
   # print(File.read())
  #  print("File Print Successfull On Line ", get_linenumber())
   # File.write("\nRawrar")

 




if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

I tried printing the data from the file, then when that worked. I attempted to convert the Num Variable to a decrypted version of the encrypted text. When that didn't work I messed with the parameters a bit. But I got no where, not to sure what Im doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem in this case seems to be the fact that you correctly convert FileToEncrypt into bytes for encryption, but when you save it you simply cast it as a string using `str()`. What you want to do instead is use `.decode()`
Furthemore you'd probably want to add another linebreak when you write the data to the file. Otherwise you will face issues if you append multiple times to the same file
`File.write(f"{EncryptionDescription}\n" + FileEncrypted + "\n")` You'd also want to make sure that when loading this data that you convert it to bytes again using `bytes(str, 'utf-8')`.

Now that your data is properly saved into the File.txt file, you are now ready to decode the data. However you will still face an error as you do not pass a timestamp in the decrypt function call, as per [the documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/). Essentially I found two ways to do this. One would simply be to call the function with a very high number as the `ttl` paramater like this: `print(Fernet.decrypt(f,bytes(num, "utf-8"), 1000000))`

 The proper way to do this is to use the function `extract_timestamp()` as per [the documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/). I implemented it like this `encryptionTimeStamp = Fernet.extract_timestamp(f, bytes(num, 'utf-8'))` with success.
Doing this will get you the unix timestamp at the time of encryption. The `ttl` parameter is the number of seconds since encryption, you'd want to take the "current unix timestamp - unix timestamp at encryption" and pass that as the `ttl`parameter.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from inspect import currentframe
import time
key = "kdQGjocgILOLXj6k_mkkOJOxHxXJji7kdRUTtrGZBTo="
f = Fernet(key)


def get_linenumber():
    cf = currentframe()
    return cf.f_back.f_lineno


def Main():

    choice = input("1. Write Raw Data To File For Encryption\n2. Read Data From File For Decryption\n\nEnter Option Here: ")
    if choice == "1":
        print("Init Main Successfull On Line ", get_linenumber())
        File = open(r"File.txt",mode="a")


        FileToEncrypt = bytes(input("Input data to encrypt, Note it will be stored as a string, then heavily encrypted with SHA-256.\n"),'utf-8')
        print("\nSuccesfully printed File To Encrypt data on line ",get_linenumber,"\nData From FileToEncrypt Var: ",FileToEncrypt)
    
        FileEncrypted = f.encrypt(FileToEncrypt)
        FileEncrypted = FileEncrypted.decode()
        print("\n\n\Here is the final product: ",FileEncrypted)
        EncryptionDescription = input("What Is The Data Entered. (Explain For Future Reference!!!)\n\nEnter Here: ")
        File.write(f"{EncryptionDescription}\n" + FileEncrypted + "\n")
    
        File.close()


    elif choice == "2":
        print("\n\nYou Have Chosen Decryption Method!\n")
        File = open(r"File.txt",mode="r")
        
        for line in File:
            name = line.strip()
            num = File.readline()
            numBytes = bytes(num, 'utf-8')
            encryptionTimeStamp = Fernet.extract_timestamp(f, numBytes)
            currentTime = int(time.time())
            timeElapsed = currentTime - encryptionTimeStamp
            print( Fernet.decrypt(f,numBytes, timeElapsed))
            
           
            
            

        
          
        

    else:
        print("Sorry, We Do Not Recognise What You Have Entered. Please look at the options and think...")
        exit(0)
        
###Debug Shit
    #print(Fernet.generate_key()) # so i can find one key and keep it static:) 
   # print(File.read())
  #  print("File Print Successfull On Line ", get_linenumber())
   # File.write("\nRawrar")

 




if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```